# Use user-created GIS layer for online survey

Tags: arcmap, shapefile

I'd like to achieve the creation of an online survey where, within a particular study area, different social groups can indicate their use (presence/absence).

In ArcMap (offline) I have a layer containing the study site, which overlays a fishnet with a total number of grid cells of a particular size. I'd like to use these 2 layers as a map in an online survey, where groups can indicate by clicking, per grid cell, if they use the area within that cell.

My questions are:

1. Whether this is indeed possible and
2. How I would go on about it and
3. What survey website can be used for this. I'm relatively inexperienced with GIS and have never done an online survey.

Comment: Survey123 is an ESRI application for use with ArcGIS data.  It can capture spatial information as well as non-spatial attributes.  It can work offline or online.  It needs to work with feature services either hosted in ArcGIS Online, ArcGIS Portal, or with feature services service by ArcGIS Server and proxied in ArcGIS Online.  **Do you have ArcGIS Server and/or ArcGIS Online?**  (See:  https://survey123.arcgis.com/ )

Comment: yes i do, i just created an account. I'll have a look into it, thanks!